# Solidity Functions Not Returning Expected Data

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I have a contract with the following function:

```
 function supply () constant returns (uint sup) {
    sup = 100;
    return sup;
  }
```

Running

```
  var token = web3.eth.contract(contractAbi).at(contractAddress);
  token.supply.call()
```

returns:

```
{ [String: '0'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] }
```

What's wrong here?  This is happening with all my functions in the contract.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting "BigNumber" format which is always the case for uint(256) because the numbers are larger than Javascript can actually handle.

Consider playing with the returned value format. Examples/docs here: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#a-note-on-big-numbers-in-web3js

Truffle style (promise)

```
token.supply.call().then(function(returned) {
   console.log(returned.toString(10));
}
```

Callback style

```
token.supply.call(function(error, returned) {
  if(!error) {
    console.log(returned.toString(10));
  } else {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Above examples will possibly loose some precision. From the doc linked above ...

> it is recommended to keep you balance always in wei and only transform
>   it to other units when presenting to the user:

Hope it helps.

**Update:**

The contract works for me in Remix, so I would focus on the way you're calling the function and **waiting for the response**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rob, can you see any reason why I'm not getting the expected 100 back, but instead getting 0?

Comment: Are you in geth, truffle console or something else? Are you waiting for the callback?

Comment: Thanks Rob, that clears things up.  I am using a truffle and testrpc and using exec to test things.  I have everything working now, I wasn't updating the contract address with each new deploy.